# Watch Property Doesn't work in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frameworks, vuejs2, frontend

I started to learn Vuejs, in the middle of a job I tried to test the Watch property but it doesn't work for me, can you tell what's wrong with the below code?

```
<div id="k2c">
    Kilometers : <input v-model= "Kilometers">
    Meters : <input v-model = "Meters"> 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var vr = new Vue({ 
        el:'#k2c',
        data:{
            Kilometers: 0;
            Meters : 0;
        },

        methods:{

        },
        computed:{
        },
        watch : {
            Kilometers : function(val){   
                this.Kilometers = val;
                this.Meters = val * 1000;  
            },    
            Meters : function(val){
                this.Kilometers = val / 1000;
                this.Meters = val;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating the properties inside their watchers. Don't, it is not necessary. Apart from it, you had other problems (see comments below).

Recommended reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="k2c">
  Kilometers : <input v-model="Kilometers">
  Meters : <input v-model="Meters">
</div>
<script>
var vr = new Vue({
  el: '#k2c',
  data: {
    Kilometers: 0,          // replaced ; with ,
    Meters: 0               // removed ; here
  },
  methods: {

  },
  computed: {},
  watch: {
    Kilometers: function(val) {
      //this.Kilometers = val;         // commented out this line, you should remove it
      this.Meters = val * 1000;
    },
    Meters: function(val) {
      this.Kilometers = val / 1000;
      //this.Meters = val;             // commented out this line, you should remove it
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

**Note:** Your two computed properties have a cyclic dependency (changing one changes the other and vice-versa). Currently this is not a problem because their values are *converging*. If this didn't happen, you'd get a stackoverflow error.

Comment: Mutating the properties inside the watcher is not necessary a problem, but in this case, it is indeed not needed. However, the semicolons in the data is the real problem here

Comment: Thanks, the problem was use ';' symbol. I used train PHP and end of each line put ';' is necessary job end of a line, it's little hard to leave this attitude.